# What are the three attack combos for Infinity Blade?

Tags: infinity-blade

There are three attack combos in Infinity Blade: 3×, 4×, 5×.

3× combo is RIGHT, LEFT, RIGHT.

Does anybody know the other two?

Comment: UP UP DOWN DOWN LEFT RIGHT LEFT RIGHT B A SELECT START

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Huge**: Up Down Up

**Mega**: Up Up Down Down

**Ultra**: Up Down Left Right Up

Comment: Left/Right/Left and Left/Left/Right/Right work as well.

Comment: Left/Left/Down/Down is a mega too.

Comment: It sounds like Left and Up are interchangeable in combos, then. I bet Right and Down are interchangeable as well.

Answer (score 6):

For the highest # of XP for the combo after you kill an enemy, do Up/Down/Up,Up/Down/Left/Right/Up for a 3x then 5x combo. You need perfect timing to do a 5x combo twice, and if you fail, you will only get the first 5x combo with only a few points for no second combo.

Answer (score -1):

The 3 combos are:

- Huge: <kbd>Left</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd>
- Mega: <kbd>Left</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd>
- Ultra: <kbd>Left</kbd> <kbd>Right</kbd> <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Down</kbd> <kbd>Left</kbd>