# What combos exist in Infinity Blade 2?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

The original Infinity Blade had [three attack combos for 3, 4, and 5 hits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12471/what-are-the-three-attack-combos-for-infinity-blade) respectively. Do the same combos work in Infinity Blade II, and are there any new ones?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The IB1 combos are still valid in IB2, but only for Sword-and-Shield style fighting. These are the available combos:

**Sword and Shield**

3-Hit Combo

- Direction 1, Opposite Direction, Direction 1
- Example: *Left, Right, Left* or *Up, Down, Up*
- Final Strike Damage: 200%

4-Hit Combo

- Direction 1, Direction 1, Opposite Direction, Opposite Direction
- Example: *Left, Left, Right, Right* or *Up, Up, Down, Down*
- Final Strike Damage: 250%

5-Hit Combo

- Direction 1, Opposite Direction, Direction 3, Opposite-3rd Direction, Direction 3
- Example: *Left, Right, Up, Down, Up* or *Up, Down, Left, Right, Left*
- Final Strike Damage: 300%

**Heavy Weapon**

The heavy weapon combo requires you to swing in a direction specified on-screen when the combo is being carried out.

- Direction 1, Direction 1, Specified Direction
- Example: Left, Left, Up (shown on screen)

**Dual Weapon**

The dual weapon combo requires you to activate the combo with a set sequence, then swipe as many times as you can in any directions to accumulate damage.

- Direction 1, Direction 2, Direction 1, Any Directions (repeat)
- Example: Left, Right, Left, (more swiping in random directions)

If you want to maximize your damage with dual weapons, you can follow the following sequence of attacks. Left, Right, Left, Up, Down, Left/Right. Assuming X is the damage you do in a single normal attack, your damage from this combo will be... X,X,2X,2X,2X,3x.

Comment: Can you make this more complete for someone who doesn't already know the IB combos?   (As written, It sounds like direction 2 can be any direction other than the direction 1 one, but I'm not certain.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jaydles I've updated to clarify. It does appear that you have to use the opposite direction of your first hit. I tried, for example, left, up, left and it did not count as a combo.

Comment: For dual weapons you can actually finish the combo, Siris will do a cross slash with both swords. I like to use left right left up down up. I think it works with combos where you change to a perpendicular direction, but I'm not sure exactly what the condition for the last hit is.

Answer (score 4):

Combos seem to be dependant on the weapon style you're using.

For sword and shield it's like in IB1, listed on here already.

For heavy weapons you basically just swipe twice in the same direction and then the direction that is displayed on screen.

For dual swords I've only found one combo as of yet and that's left, right, left (or right, left, right), one you have started the combo you can just keep swiping in different directions and each swipe will also count as a combo swipe and do extra damage.

I'd love to know if there are more combo intros for dual swords though, can't just be the one...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that with dual sword you can use this combo:
example: Left, right and left left, now you got a combo  right right or what ever more
.                          (Fast)

Answer (score 0):

Dual weapon you can choose this combo: Left, Right, Left, Right, Right, Left, Up

You end up with a "X" hit with higher damage

Answer (score -1):

Dual wield one I found was left right left right left up

Answer (score -1):

You can use "down" at the end with dual weapons instead of "up". It will be like "I I".